# Double THE template issue

Tags: bug, user-interface

Is the double **the** from the inbox notification (pictured below) a template issue or are we rolling with it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it’s just a template issue. There’s not many sites here that have names starting with “The”.

We’ll get that sorted out. Thank for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not a bug. "The Workplace" is the name of the site, so "the 'The Workplace' election" is (arguably) technically correct (even if it sounds a little awkward).

Comment: Probably, yes. The site is called "The Workplace"... So, if we rearrange the sentence it'd read "The 2019 community moderator election on The Workplace is underway..." Or, even "The 2019 The Workplace community..."  I'm guessing that none of y'all'd have an issue with this, so, by turning "The Workplace" into an adjective would retain the "The".